# Need to remove this special chars from the string php

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a string from a database which contains special characters.

I need to remove `"”foreign_language_keywords”"` from the string. Note the special `”`, that is creating problems.
I used this:

```
$d_contents = str_replace(
     "”foreign_language_keywords”",
     "foreign_language_keywords",
     $d_contents
);
```

but it is returning the same thing.

This is the page http://www.residentialstores.com/product_detail/bluetooth-keyboard--case-for-ipad-mini--qwerty-detachable-keyboard-flip-stand-black where I am having issue, I need to remove or hide foreign language keywords shown in description  like "Arabic- ......."
all this are in

tag having id "”foreign_language_keywords”" so it beocmes Arabic-  .....

I need to hide this p tag

Comment: [`addslashes()`](http://us1.php.net/addslashes)?

Comment: Not working, this is the page http://www.residentialstores.com/product_detail/bluetooth-keyboard--case-for-ipad-mini--qwerty-detachable-keyboard-flip-stand-black where I am having issue, I need to remove or hide foreign language keywords shown in description  like "Arabic- ......."
all this are in <p> tag having id "”foreign_language_keywords”" so it beocmes <p id="”foreign_language_keywords”">Arabic-  .....</p>
I need to hide this p tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your code actually do the `str_replace()`, or that you are actually working on the same string after?

These both works fine here:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<? 

$d_contents = "<p><strong>
<p id='”foreign_language_keywords”'>Arabic - الحال بالنسبة
لأي باد ميني مع لوحة مفاتيح bluetooth قابلة للنزع; Chinese 
Simplified - 可拆卸的蓝牙��盘与 iPad 迷你的情况; Czech ... ";


$d_contents = str_replace("”", "", $d_contents);

print "$d_contents\n";
```

Or using:

```
$d_contents = str_replace(
    "”foreign_language_keywords”",
    "foreign_language_keywords",
    $d_contents
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this:

```
$d_contents = str_replace("”", "", $d_contents);
```

This way it's shortened and easier to read.

Comment: Not working, this is the page http://www.residentialstores.com/product_detail/bluetooth-keyboard--case-for-ipad-mini--qwerty-detachable-keyboard-flip-stand-black where I am having issue, I need to remove or hide foreign language keywords shown in description  like "Arabic- ......."
all this are in <p> tag having id "”foreign_language_keywords”" so it beocmes <p id="”foreign_language_keywords”">Arabic-  .....</p>
I need to hide this p tag

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$d_contents = str_replace('”foreign_language_keywords”','foreign_language_keywords',$d_contents);
```

it will work